# Call to a member function has() on string in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on user authentication. When a user provides invalid email or password, I want to redirect him to `login.blade.php` with a flash error message.

```
// Auth/LoginController:

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user=User::where('email',$request->email)->first();

    if(!is_null($user))
    {
        if($user->status==1)
        {
            if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember))

                return redirect()->intended(route('index'));

            }

        }

        else
        {

            if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember))
            {
                if(Auth::check())
                {
                    Auth::logout();
                }
            $user->notify(new VerifyRegistration($user));
            session()->flash('success','A new confirmation mail has sent to you...Please check and confirm your email');
            return redirect('/');
            }
            else
            {
                session()->flash('errors','Password is incorrect!!');
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

        session()->flash('errors','Email or Password is incorrect!!');
            return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

I am using the default laravel [`login.blade.php`](https://snipsave.com/mishudas/#/).

Comment: What is not working? Please, be clearer.

Comment: When I am providing wrong email or password, it is not redirecting me to login.blade.php. It is showing me the error,

Comment: "Call to a member function has() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)"

Comment: The exception says the issue is coming from the view, not the controller. Can you provide your view's code?

Comment: Can you include all the code from your `\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php` including the part with the  `has()` method that is causing the error?

Comment: Here is my login.blade.php          https://snipsave.com/mishudas/#/

Comment: It seems that your not doing any validation on the email/password? If thats the case then the `$errors` array will not be set in your blade. You should either validate the input  (in your controller, or using a custom Request class) 
 or remove the $error handling from the template if your not using it.

Comment: Obviously I am doing validation sir. I just wrote my code in short.

Comment: $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]); is inside LoginController

Comment: It's not obvious if you don't include it in the question... can you include all your code, so we can help you.

Comment: Yes it works when I write return redirect()->route('login')->with('errorsnew','Invalid password.'); When I run foreach loop on errors, it shows the error.

Comment: Now LoginController, login.blade.php and messsage.blade.php is:  https://snipsave.com/mishudas/#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user enter's wrong password rather than setting up session flash message please use below given code to redirect user in else condition.

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with('error','Invalid password.');
```

On login template you can display errors like

```
           @if (session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
              <p>{{ session('success') }}</p>
            </div>
            @endif

            @if (session('warning'))
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <p>{{ session('warning') }}</p>
                </div>
            @endif

            @if (session('error'))
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <p>{{ session('error') }}</p>
                </div>
            @endif
```

Comment: You are right, but your answer should be a comment as it doesn't resolve the author's issue.

Comment: @KévinBibollet It most likely will solve the authors issue, as the authors issue is caused the `$errors` object being null on the `login.blade.php`. So the `$errors->has()` method is returning an error.

Comment: I think Author has issue in their if condition because in most cases above mentioned syntax passes flash message to view. @KévinBibollet

Comment: Yes it works when I write   return redirect()->route('login')->with('errorsnew','Invalid password.');  When I run foreach loop on errors, it shows the error.

Comment: On errors means validation error ? If yes post which error you are getting please.

Comment: Call to a member function has() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php) this error